# calling String value of date in another class as Date variable

Tags: java, string, datetime, constructor, subclass

[image]

I have a date of birth in string in Date class and I want to call it as Date variable in another class using constructor, HealthProfile as per my uml diagram. How can I do that? And also, what is the Scanner input type for Date? I have done other parts and below code is my getDateString method in Date class.

```
public String getDateString()
    {
        String dob = String.valueOf(day) + month + String.valueOf(year);
        return dob;
    }
```

The date of birth format I was trying to print is, example: 8 October 2000. I have a txt file of such data and trying to call from it.

Comment: So what is data structure of your `Date` Class? I guess you want to input date/month/year and return the whole string about birthday???

Comment: The date of birth format I was trying to print is, example: 8 October 2000. I have a txt file of such data and trying to call from it.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Supplying further information to a question is often a good idea and welcome. Please do so *in the question itself* (edit it) since many readers either don’t want to read through the comments or simply don’t do it. This time only I edited the question for you.

Answer (score 0):

I help you to create a `Date` Class with a contruct method.
In main class, i help you to use `System.in` to input data string and return what you method want.

Date Class:

```java
public class Date {
    int year;
    String month;
    int day;

    public Date(int year, String month, int day) {
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }
    
    /**
    * Getter and Setter methods
    */

    public String getDateString(){
        String dob = String.valueOf(day) + month + String.valueOf(year);
        return dob;
    }
```

Test main class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputstr = scanner.nextLine(); //you enter 24-07-2020

        String[] inputarr = inputstr.split(" ");
        Date date = new Date(Integer.valueOf(inputarr[2]), inputarr[1], Integer.valueOf(inputarr[0]));

        System.out.println(date.getDateString());

    }
```

Comment: You may want to mention that creating one’s own `Date` class is only something one would do as an exercise (not in production).

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Scanner` hasn’t got a method for reading an instance of your `Date` class (it may be obvious). I suggest that you use

- `nextInt()` for reading the day of month (e.g., 8)
- `next()` for reading the month name (e.g., `October`)
- `nextInt()` for reading the year (e.g., 2000)

With the three values thus obtained you can call your constructor `Date(int day, String month, int year)`. As you may know, a `Scanner` can read from a text file.

Aside from this (ignore if you can’t use it):

1. For the conversion back to a string I suggest that you put spaces between the elements to get like `8 October 2000` again rather than `8October2000`, which is unpleasant to read.
2. One may consider an enum for the months. It will complicate input, but will provide validation that a correct month name is entered. If this is not part of your requirement, you may leave this comment for other readers.
3. For production work one would use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and not develop one’s own `Date` class.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.